# COUNT (*) = 0 does not work?

Tags: ms-access

Alright, I'm trying to make a query for a library that will show which students have never borrowed a book. For this, I have done the following:

```
SELECT
    LEERLINGEN.LLNR,
    LEERLINGEN.VOORNAAM,
    LEERLINGEN.TUSSENVOEGSEL,
    LEERLINGEN.ACHTERNAAM,
    LEERLINGEN.KLAS,
    COUNT(*) AS AANTAL
FROM
    UITLENINGEN
    INNER JOIN LEERLINGEN ON UITLENINGEN.LLNR = LEERLINGEN.LLNR
GROUP BY
    LEERLINGEN.LLNR,
    LEERLINGEN.VOORNAAM,
    LEERLINGEN.TUSSENVOEGSEL,
    LEERLINGEN.ACHTERNAAM,
    LEERLINGEN.KLAS
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 0;
```

This doesn't seem to work for some reason, as all it does is create an empty table when I click <kbd>Execute</kbd>.

What did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use an outer join, otherwise you won't get those students back that did not borrow a book.

Then you need to count() on the students table, not "the group" (which is done when you use `(*)`)

```
SELECT
    LEERLINGEN.LLNR,
    LEERLINGEN.VOORNAAM,
    LEERLINGEN.TUSSENVOEGSEL,
    LEERLINGEN.ACHTERNAAM,
    LEERLINGEN.KLAS,
    COUNT(LEERLINGEN.LLNR) AS AANTAL
FROM
    LEERLINGEN
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UITLENINGEN ON UITLENINGEN.LLNR = LEERLINGEN.LLNR
GROUP BY
    LEERLINGEN.LLNR,
    LEERLINGEN.VOORNAAM,
    LEERLINGEN.TUSSENVOEGSEL,
    LEERLINGEN.ACHTERNAAM,
    LEERLINGEN.KLAS
HAVING
    COUNT(UITLENINGEN.LLNR) = 0;
```

I dont' know MS-Access, but I assume it supports outer joins using standard SQL.

Comment: I have found the issue: turns out the database I was given did not have a single student in it who had never borrowed a book.

Following some modifications to the LEERLINGEN table, this query is the one that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

After translation of table names i think that this will work:

```
SELECT
    LEERLINGEN.LLNR,
    LEERLINGEN.VOORNAAM,
    LEERLINGEN.TUSSENVOEGSEL,
    LEERLINGEN.ACHTERNAAM,
    LEERLINGEN.KLAS

FROM
    LEERLINGEN 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN UITLENINGEN ON UITLENINGEN.LLNR = LEERLINGEN.LLNR
WHERE 
    UITLENINGEN.LLNR IS NULL;
```

EDIT:
You are looking for LEERLINGEN where there is no UITLENINGEN at all. 
Check this alternative:

```
SELECT
    LEERLINGEN.LLNR,
    LEERLINGEN.VOORNAAM,
    LEERLINGEN.TUSSENVOEGSEL,
    LEERLINGEN.ACHTERNAAM,
    LEERLINGEN.KLAS

FROM
    LEERLINGEN 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM UITLENINGEN WHERE LLNR = LEERINGEN.LLNR
)
```

Comment: I have found the issue: turns out the database I was given did not have a single student in it who had never borrowed a book.

Comment: +1 for the alternative answers. Both `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` and `NOT EXISTS` should outperform the `LEFT JOIN / GROUP BY / COUNT()=0` variant. There is no need to count borrows for every student, only find those that haven't borrowed anything.